# Workbox: getting a new service worker while offline, delay between installin and waiting to activate

Tags: progressive-web-apps, service-worker, workbox

I am developin a Progressive Web App and would like to make life as easy as posible for the users when a new service worker is received since the app needs to be reopen.

At first, using workbox-config.js I asked for running self.skipWaiting to be executed when the 'SKIP_WAITING' is received. This code was added in sw.js:

```html
  self.addEventListener('message', event => {
    if (event.data && event.data.type === 'SKIP_WAITING') {
      self.skipWaiting();
    }
```

But that didn't work, the service worker was still waiting to be activated. The code is still in sw,js.

I google and found out some code I could use to display a message to the user asking him to close the app and restart it. I added this code in index.html

```html
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  window.addEventListener('load', async function() {
      const registration = await navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js');
      if (registration.waiting && registration.active) {
          alert('Fermer l\'application afin d\'appliquer la mise-a-jour');
    } else {
        // updatefound is also fired for the very first install
        registration.addEventListener('updatefound', () => {
            registration.installing.addEventListener('statechange', () => {
              if (event.target.state === 'installed') {
                if (registration.active) {
                  // If there's already an active SW, and skipWaiting() is not
                  // called in the SW, then the user needs to close all their
                  // tabs before they'll get updates
                  alert('Fermer l\'application afin d\'appliquer la mise-a-jour');
              } else {
                console.log('Content is cached for the first time!');
              }
            }
          });
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

At first I thought that didn't work, because the alert was not displayed, but I was wrong. I made this test and found out there was a delay induced, see

1. Started the App
2. Unsing Dev Tools I checked Offline
3. Change something and generated a new service worker
4. Deployed the app again
5. I unchecked Offline
6. A service worker was trying to install
7. **About 5 minutes later the service worker was installed and waiting**
8. And then I got the alert.

What is the explanation for the 5 minutes delay ?

Thanks a lot

Gilles Plante

Answer (score 0):

Your web app won't automatically check for an updated service worker unless one of the [following conditions](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/lifecycle#updates) are met:

> - A navigation to an in-scope page.
> - A functional events such as push and sync, unless there's been an update check within the previous 24 hours.
> - Calling .register() only if the service worker URL has changed. However, you should avoid changing the worker URL.

In practice, unless you have a single-page app, most of your users will end up triggering a service worker update check each time they navigate to a new page. But if you have a single-page app that uses the History API instead of "real" navigations, it's possible the check won't happen as often as you'd like.

You can work around this by [manually calling](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/lifecycle#manual_updates) the `update()` method on your service worker registration:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js').then(reg => {
  // sometime later…
  reg.update();
});
```